# How to deduplicate based upon an interval between dates in same column

Tags: r, date, duplicates

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
ID     Date          Type
1      2019/03/12      A
1      2019/03/12      A
2      2019/01/07      A
2      2019/04/20      B
3      2019/02/09      C
4      2019/01/19      A
4      2019/01/23      A
```

I want to deduplicate this table by ID, but only if the span between the dates listed is greater than 7 days. If it is less than 7 days, then I want to keep the earliest date.

Want:

```
ID     Date          Type
1      2019/03/12      A
2      2019/01/07      A
2      2019/04/20      B
3      2019/02/09      C
4      2019/01/19      A
```

I'm just struggling with where to start conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to convert the 'Date' to `Date` class (`ymd` from `lubridate` is used here), then grouped by 'ID', `filter` the `diff`erence of 'Date' that is greater than or equal to 7

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%
  group_by(ID)  %>% 
  filter(c(TRUE, diff(Date) >= 7))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   ID [4]
#     ID Date       Type 
#  <int> <date>     <chr>
#1     1 2019-03-12 A    
#2     2 2019-01-07 A    
#3     2 2019-04-20 B    
#4     3 2019-02-09 C    
#5     4 2019-01-19 A
```

data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), Date = c("2019/03/12", 
"2019/03/12", "2019/01/07", "2019/04/20", "2019/02/09", "2019/01/19", 
"2019/01/23"), Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```